# Verify that String input by user is correct

Tags: java, string

I have an array of Strings such as:

```
String [] teams = {"Manchester City", "Chelsea", "Barcelona", "Bayern Munich", "Juventus", "Tottenham", "Liverpool", "Basel", "PSG", "Real Madrid", "Porto" + 
"Besiktas", "Sevilla", "Manchester United", "Roma", "Shaktar Donetsk"};
```

My program code where I need help:

```
System.out.print("\nWho do you think will win?: ");
String winner = sc.nextLine();

team: while (teamValid) {

    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length ; i++) {

         if (!(winner.equalsIgnoreCase(teams[i])))
             counter++;

         if (counter == 16) {
             System.out.print("\nWho do you think will win?: ");
             winner = sc.nextLine();    
             teamValid = false;
             break;
         }

        if ((winner.equalsIgnoreCase(teams[i]))) {
             break team;
        }
    }

}

System.out.println(winner);
```

What I want to do is prompt a user to enter one of the teams in this String array. If he enters the name wrong (ignoring cases), then I ask again to enter that team. This is what I have. I understand that my logical error occurs in the:

```
if (counter == 16) {
    System.out.print("\nWho do you think will win?: ");
    winner = sc.nextLine(); 
    teamValid = false;
    break;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If I read the question correct, shouldn't `teams.contains(winner)` be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use do while loop instead, and with Java 8 you can solve your problem like this :

```
String winner; boolean check;
do {
    System.out.print("\nWho do you think will win?: ");
    winner = sc.nextLine();
    //check if there are a team in your array, with (ignoring cases)
    check = Arrays.asList(teams).stream().anyMatch(winner::equalsIgnoreCase);

} while (!check);

System.out.println(winner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the teams, that makes no sense.

Instead, you should maybe try:

1. perform a Do-While instead of While
2. Iterate over the list only when you read the answer, meaning (psuedo code):

   ```
   do {
     potentialWinner = sc.read()
   for (each team){
     if (potentialWinner.ignoreCaseEquals(team)
        winner = potentialWinner
        break
      }
   } while (winner == null)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```
input: while (true) {
    String winner = sc.nextLine();
    for (String name : teams) {
        if (winner.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            break input;
        }
    }
}
```

This will take an input and check whether it exists within the Array. If it does not, it will prompt the user for another input and reiterate through the Array until a valid input is found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you can use `Arrays.asList` to convert your `String[]` to a `List`, and then use the `Predicate<String>` from `winner::equalsIgnoreCase` in a `do-while` loop. And you can `negate()` that `Predicate` to determine "everyone else". Like,

```
String[] teams = { "Manchester City", "Chelsea", "Barcelona", "Bayern Munich",
        "Juventus", "Tottenham", "Liverpool", "Basel", "PSG", "Real Madrid",
        "Porto", "Besiktas", "Sevilla", "Manchester United", "Roma", "Shaktar Donetsk" };
List<String> teamList = Arrays.asList(teams);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String winner;
do {
    System.out.print("\nWho do you think will win?: ");
    winner = sc.nextLine();
} while (!teamList.stream().anyMatch(winner::equalsIgnoreCase));
System.out.printf("You like %s?%n", winner);
Predicate<String> predicate = (Predicate<String>) winner::equalsIgnoreCase;
System.out.printf("I think %s will knock them out this year%n", teamList.stream()
        .filter(predicate.negate()).collect(Collectors.joining(" or ")));
```

Example run:

```
Who do you think will win?: basel
You like basel?
I think Manchester City or Chelsea or Barcelona or Bayern Munich or Juventus or Tottenham or Liverpool or PSG or Real Madrid or Porto or Besiktas or Sevilla or Manchester United or Roma or Shaktar Donetsk will knock them out this year
```